# Wrong result when I combine multiplication result that is in a for each

Tags: php, foreach

Maybe it's the lack of sleep, but Here's my issue :

```
$totalAllow = 0;
foreach ($pictPrices  as $pictPrice) {
                    foreach ($picsAllow as $key => $value) {
                        $totalAllow += $value * $pictPrice['price'];
                        dd($totalAllow);
                    }
                    dd($totalAllow);
                }
$picsAllowTotal = $totalAllow;
```

My `$value` (here 3, 2, 1, 5) times my `$pictPrice['price']` (here 80, 100, 150, 35) in the first `dd($totalAllow)` I did gave me the result I expect, 240. Why in the 2nd `dd($totalAllow)` I get 480?

In my `$picsAllowTotal` I expect 765 (for (3x80)+(2x100)+(1x150)+(5x35)), but It isn't! It's 4015.

Can you explain me where is my mistake?

Thank you for your time.

----------- ANSWER -----------

```
$totalAllow = 0;        
for ($price = 0; $price < count($pictPrices); $price++){
            $totalAllow += array_values($picsAllow)[$price] * $pictPrices[$price]['price'];
        }
```

Comment: can you include both values of `$picsAllow` and `$pictPrices` in the question?

Comment: sure, $picsAllow ( key : value )  : 1 : 3,  2 : 2,  3 : 1,  4 : 5 , and $pictPrices is my db row, with an 'id' , 'sizes' and 'price'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your code sums up the result of multiplying every member of one array by every member of the second array. You don't need nested loops to get the expected result.

Try this code:

```
<?php

// 80, 100, 150, 35
$pictPrices = [
    ['price'=>80],
    ['price'=>100],
    ['price'=>150],
    ['price'=>35],
];

// 3, 2, 1, 5
$picsAllow = [
    3, 2, 1, 5
];

$totalAllow = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < count($pictPrices); $i++) { 
    $totalAllow += $picsAllow[$i] * $pictPrices[$i]['price'];
    dd($totalAllow);
}

function dd($val) { echo $val . "\r\n"; }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's getting me closer, but, as my $picsAllow = [ 12x24 => 3, 21x56 =>2 etc... ] , it give me an undefined offset, I don't know if a 'for' can have two conditions, otherwise how can I do?

Comment: ok, just did array_values($picsAllow)[$price] instead, Thank you again.